# How does Minerva know that it was Ginny that was missing?

Tags: harry-potter

In *HP and the Chamber of Secrets*, when Ginny Weasley was taken into the Chamber of Secrets how did Minerva McGonagall and the other teachers know it was **her** that had been taken?

If anyone had seen it happening, wouldn't they have been attacked by the monster as well?

Comment: Are you asking how they knew she was in the chamber of secrets?

Comment: I think this was because of the final message she wrote in blood.... I think. Not sure though.

Comment: I'm not sure if the message said explicitly who had been taken, though. Pretty sure it's never clarified in the books. It's possible it was a process of elimination; Ginny wasn't where she was supposed to be at that time, hadn't returned to the Gryffindor common room, etc. so they assumed she must have been the student that was taken. I don't know if the timeline works for that, though.

Comment: I would suggest it's in the message. Although we don't see the message, Riddle says: "So I made Ginny write her own farewell on the wall and come down
here to wait."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the chapter carefully, the answer is in plain sight:

> But the bell to signal break never came. Instead, echoing through the
>   corridors came Professor McGonagall’s voice, magically magnified.
>
> ‘**All students to return to their house dormitories at once.** All
>   teachers return to the staff room. Immediately, please.’

later

> ‘Right,’ said Professor McGonagall, whose nostrils were flared,
>   ‘that’s got him out from under our feet. The Heads of Houses should go
>   and inform their students what has happened. Tell them the Hogwarts
>   Express will take them home first thing tomorrow. **Will the rest of you
>   please make sure no students have been left outside their
>   dormitories.’**

The clear implication is that the students are taken straight from their lessons and **locked** into their dormitories. Since Ginny must have either been missing from her lesson (or at the very least failed to return to her assigned dorm room), from that point onwards it should be very easy to determine whose "skeleton will lie in the Chamber for ever" by the simple expedient of working out which female student is missing.

[image]

Comment: If they do a headcount of students, then wouldn’t she have remarked that Harry and Ron were also missing from their dormitory?

Comment: @alexwlchan - They know a girl is missing ("***her*** skeleton") so they're only counting missing girls. McGonagall knew that Harry and Ron were in the infirmary so their being missing wouldn't have raised serious eyebrows...

Comment: Maybe. I would expect McGonagall to notice that her brother was missing, but she may well have been in a hurry.

Comment: That second quote you've posted comes *after* she's already said that it was Ginny Weasley, though. It's possible that they were able to do a very quick check to figure out Ginny was missing, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Good point and I've edited accordingly. The students are taken from their classes to their rooms. One of the tutors may have already noted her absence from lessons...

Comment: @alexwlchan Harry and Ron were known from the previous year to have a habit of wandering out of the dormitory when they weren't allowed.  Maybe Professor McGonagall did notice they were missing and thought that if the monster caught them despite the clear precautions, it's their own fault.  Ginny missing was much more worrying.  :-)

Comment: @b_jonas: I know Hogwarts take a lax attitude to student safety, but it’s not *that* lax.

Comment: @b_jonas - She'd already given them permission to go to the infirmary to see Hermione.

Comment: still doesn't answer HOW she knew it was Ginny? assuming McGonagall quoted the phrase verbatim then there is no clear way she knew it was Ginny for sure?

Comment: @bp_phoenix - As I said, there's clearly been some (unseen by us) delay while they did a headcount

Comment: Ginny had three brothers who would have been in the dormitory along with her.  Percy, especially, would have taken it upon himself to check on everybody.

Answer (score 5):

When Harry and Ron are hiding in the teachers' wardrobe, this is what they hear:

> "The Heir of Slytherin," said Professor McGonagall, who was very
>   white, "left another message. Right underneath the first one.*'Her
>   skeleton will lie in the chamber forever.'*"
>
> Professor Flitwick burst into tears.
>
> "Who is it?" said Madam Hooch, who had sunk, weak-kneed, into a chair.
>   "Which student?"
>
> "Ginny Weasley," said Professor McGonagall.

It's not clear what exactly was the message. Professor McGonagall reports that it said 'Her skeleton will lie in the Chamber forever'. Whether the real full message specified which particular person or not is still not clear. However, one of two things can be inferred:

1. The message does not say which student it was, but the teachers do a role call in all the Houses and find out who is missing.
2. Since Ginny was also bait to lure Harry towards the Chamber by the memory Tom Riddle, the full message itself said that it was Ginny (so that the message would reach Harry quickly and clearly) (although, as already mentioned, this is just speculation).

Comment: I think you might be mistaken. McGonagall seems to be relaying the message verbatim...

Answer (score -4):

I think Minerva has seen Ginny going inside the Chamber of Secrets, or it may be Ginny who was absent in her classes. Of course, at that time all were worried about the opening of Chamber Of Secrets, so they thought he took Ginny.